# slick 2d, Java, Animation getters and setters

Tags: java, animation, slick2d

i'm trying to develop a game and it's still early days, but i've run into an issue.

I've created a character class and defined an animation in that class but want to use it in another class, I've made a getter for the Animation, but in the class where i want to use it, it's just returning null. The getters and setters work just fine with integers, but i cant figure this out, any help would be appreciated :)

Player class

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Animation;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Player {

int x,y,dx,dy;
Animation currentAnim, DownWalk, LeftWalk;
SpriteSheet down;



public Player(int x, int y) throws SlickException{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    currentAnim = DownWalk;
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

    down = new SpriteSheet("res/Character/DownWalkSpriteSheet",160,160);
    DownWalk = new Animation(down, 200);
    currentAnim = DownWalk;

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = gc.getInput();
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics sbg)
        throws SlickException {
    currentAnim.draw(100,100);
}

public Animation getAnim(){
    return currentAnim;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

}
```

Level class(the class i want to use it in):

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.GameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Room1 extends BasicGameState {

Image Room1;
Player player;

public Room1(int state){
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
        throws SlickException {
    Room1 = new Image("res/Room1.png");
    player = new Player(300,300);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics sbg)
        throws SlickException {
    Room1.draw(0,0);

}
```

the system.out.print is how i checked that it was returning null

```
@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
        throws SlickException {
    System.out.println(player.getAnim());

}

@Override
public int getID() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `init` Method from the Player class. Otherwise you still receive `null` instead the created Animation object.

I guess after creating the Player object you wanna call the init method:

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
        throws SlickException {
    Room1 = new Image("res/Room1.png");
    player = new Player(300,300);
    player.init(...) // HERE add the init call
}
```

Comment: If it worked you can mark the answer as solution and close the question.